# Use both 32-bit and 64-bit version of rundll32.exe in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to convert theses two lines that I have in a batch file to Inno Setup `[Run]` section:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe "%~dp0my32.dll",RegDll
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe "%~dp0my64.dll",RegDll
```

So I want something like this (but working):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\rundll32.exe"; Parameters: ""{code:GetDir|0}\my64.dll",RegDll"; WorkingDir: "{code:GetDir|0}"; StatusMsg: "Registering Module..."; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser
Filename: "{syswow64}\rundll32.exe"; Parameters: ""{code:GetDir|0}\my32.dll",RegDll"; WorkingDir: "{code:GetDir|0}"; StatusMsg: "Registering Module..."; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser
```

Comment: So, what is the actual issue? Distinguishing between 32-bit and 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct in [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls), i.e. if you have [`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode) set:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

---

In 32-bit install mode, Inno Setup, being 32-bit application, will get redirected to `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64`, when it tries to access `C:\Windows\System32`. So effectively, both `sys` and `syswow64` map to the same [32-bit] folder (`C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64`).

You can override that (if you do not want to switch to 64-bit install mode) by using [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=64bit):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\rundll32.exe"; Parameters: """{code:GetDir|0}\my64.dll"",RegDll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{code:GetDir|0}"; StatusMsg: "Registering Module..."; \
    MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser; Flags: 64bit;
Filename: "{sys}\rundll32.exe"; Parameters: """{code:GetDir|0}\my32.dll"",RegDll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{code:GetDir|0}"; StatusMsg: "Registering Module..."; \
    MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser; Flags: 32bit;
```